# Integration test in JUNIT for REST endpoint inside Lambda function?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, micronaut

I have a Micronaut Controller API configured inside Lambda. I am able to test this via Postman using a bearer token.

Controller:

```java
  @Get("v1/path")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public dto testApi(AwsProxyRequestContext context) {
    /// Some logic on the context.
  }
```

Integration test:

```java
  @Inject
  @Client("/")
  HttpClient http;

  @Test
  void testHello1() {
    MutableHttpRequest<Object> request = HttpRequest.GET("/v1/path").bearerAuth(token);
    http.toBlocking().exchange(request, dto.class);
  }
```

The test returns `Bad Request`, but if I remove the `AwsProxyRequestContext context` in the API, this `test works`.

Please help on what else should I pass in with the request to get this test working with the `AwsProxyRequestContext context`.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP client sends inacceptable data. In your test you send `dto.class` but you actually should send an instance of `AwsProxyRequestContext`.

```java
  @Test
  void testHello1() {
    MutableHttpRequest<Object> request = HttpRequest.GET("/v1/path").bearerAuth(token);
    http.toBlocking().exchange(request, new AwsProxyRequestContext(/* initialise instance properly with your data */));
  }
```